# animating two views in titanium

Tags: animation, titanium, titanium-mobile

I have two views displayed in a window as follows

```
var topView = Ti.UI.createView({
  top: 0,
  height: '65%',
  orientation: 'vertical'
});
var botView = Ti.UI.createView({
  bottom: 0,
  height: '35%',
  layout: 'vertical'
});
```

i want to animate as follows:

when a button is clicked, topView increases to hundred percent while botView decreases to 0 percent. and the reverse happens when the button is clicked.

But i haven't found a way to do it for two views.
I hope someone can help out.
Thanks -:)

EDIT:
This is what i have done so far:

```
var expandFlag = false;

/* create animations */
  var expandAnim_map = Ti.UI.createAnimation({
      height : '100%',
      duration: 300
  });
  var expandAnim_con = Ti.UI.createAnimation({
    height: '0%',
    duration : 300,
    bottom:0
  });

  var collapseAnim_map = Ti.UI.createAnimation({
      height: '65%',
      duration: 300,
  });
  var collapseAnim_con = Ti.UI.createAnimation({
      height: '35%',
      duration: 300,
      bottom:0
  });

  /* create animations */


if (expandFlag) {
  botView.animate(collapseAnim_con);
  topView.animate(collapseAnim_map);
  expandFlag = false;
} else {
  topView.animate(expandAnim_map);
  botView.animate(expandAnim_con);
  expandFlag = true;
}
```

This is irregular and not beautiful, hence i'm looking for a cleaner and smoother way to do it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you animate only one view in order to get a good looking animation.

You can set a higher zIndex for the top view, and then expand and reduce only that view.

```
var expandFlag = false;

var topView = Ti.UI.createView({
  top: 0,
  zIndex: 2,
  height: '65%',
  orientation: 'vertical'
});
var botView = Ti.UI.createView({
  bottom: 0,
  zIndex: 1,
  height: '35%',
  layout: 'vertical'
});

/* create animations */
  var expandAnim_map = Ti.UI.createAnimation({
      height : '100%',
      duration: 300
  });

  var collapseAnim_map = Ti.UI.createAnimation({
      height: '65%',
      duration: 300,
  });

  /* create animations */


if (expandFlag) {+
  topView.animate(collapseAnim_map);
  expandFlag = false;
} else {
  topView.animate(expandAnim_map);
  expandFlag = true;
}
```

Comment: I wonder what the + is doing here "if (expandFlag) {+"
It appears not to be a syntax error, but it doesn't seem to make any difference either?
Also, expanding is smooth, but collapsing the view isn't animated though

Comment: the + was a typo. It doesn't do anything. About the view collapsing with no animation I don't know what could it be...

Comment: I guess that you put the if/else part into an eventlistener, don't you?

Comment: sure, otherwise you wont be able to control when to expand and collapse the topView. Anyway, I can't see why the collapse don't get animated